# Python variable assignment: previous value updated when new value assigned

Tags: python, arrays

I have an 2D array I'm stepping through which is fed in from a text file (which accounts for me having to convert each value in the array to a float)

```
  while 1:
e=path.find(", ")
#545.423, 169.830 536.723, 164.899 529.696, 160.916 520.343, 157.377 510.990, 153.839 510.298, 153.577
ptx=path[0:e]#545.423
path=path[e+2:]
e=path.find(" ")
if e>0:
  pty=0-float(path[0:e])
  pts.append([ptx,path[0:e]])
```

I want to find if a value occurs between 2 consecutive values in the array:

```
  pta=[None]*2
  ptb=[None]*2
  y=None
  for pt in pts:
    if y==None:
      y=float(pt[1])
      continue
    if pta[0]==None:
      pta[0]=float(pt[0])
      pta[1]=float(pt[1])
      continue
    ptb[0]=float(pt[0])
    ptb[1]=float(pt[1])
    print pta[1],y,ptb[1]
    if (x>pta[0] and x<ptb[0])or(x<pta[0] and x>ptb[0]):
      .... some code ....
    pta=ptb
```

The first 'y-value' of the 2D array (it is an array of [x,y] cartesian values) is assigned to 'y', the second point is allocated to point 'A' (pta), the third to point 'B' and thereafter point 'B' is assigned to point 'A' and the new pt passed to point 'B'. The output of **print pta[1],y,ptb[1]** is as follows:

```
-196.338 -126.302 -196.338
-187.437 -126.302 -187.437
-186.951 -126.302 -186.951
-178.351 -126.302 -178.351
-170.482 -126.302 -170.482
-164.385 -126.302 -164.385
-157.085 -126.302 -157.085
-150.623 -126.302 -150.623
-146.074 -126.302 -146.074
-140.465 -126.302 -140.465
-136.278 -126.302 -136.278
-133.244 -126.302 -133.244
```

Not quite what I expected: the pta[1] and ptb[1] values are the same. I was expecting the values pta[1] and ptb[1] to be different.

```
-125.018 -126.302 -124.258
-124.258 -126.302 -124.007
-124.007 -126.302 -124.272
-124.272 -126.302 -125.045
-125.045 -126.302 -126.302
```

I need to find the position in the array where the 'y' value falls between 2 array entries.

I'm passing ptb to pta, but when I change the value of ptb to the next pt in the array, it appears to change pta as well? Or is there some stupid line in my code which I can't see?

Comment: Could you post a summary of the `pts` collection? Also, it is recommended that you show your expected output.

Comment: after `pta=ptb`, both variables refer to the SAME mutable array. if you want to **copy** all values, you need to do `pta = [p for p in ptb]`

Comment: In this case slice assignment `pta[:] = ptb` is simpler than a list comprehension

Comment: @gnerkus: I've added the array input and the expected output. Thank you. Apprilion and AChampion: That was roughly what I thought was happening. I'll read up on how to do that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your first 3 iterations, you will most likely see the two arrays with different values:

```
print pta[1],y,ptb[1]

None, 1, None  # 0
3, 1, None  # 1
3, 1, 6   # 2
4, 1, 4  # on third iteration pta is the same lst as ptb
```

On the third iteration you are setting `pta=ptb` - they are no longer distinct `lists` like you how you wanted them. Make sure you do

```
pta=list(ptb)
```

At the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with mutable objects like list, dont assign it directly as shown below

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> b = l
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> l.append(3)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(l)
3072560332L
>>> id (b)
3072560332L # both referring to same object, only with different referencing names
```

Changes in one can reflect in other.
Instead use something like,

```
b = l[:]
```

which copies the l to b, instead of accessing the same object. Now two will have separate `ids`.

Comment: Wouldn't `b[:] = l` be better to avoid the creation of lots intermediate lists?

Comment: trudat. yes it would

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simplify the iteration and comparison of 3 consecutive points if I understand correctly what you are trying to do:

```
pts = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,4), (0,3), (0,2)]
for i in range(len(pts) - 2):
    ax, ay = pts[i]
    bx, by = pts[i + 1]
    cx, cy = pts[i + 2]
    b_between_a_and_c = ay < by < cy
    print("{} is between {} and {}: {}".format(by, ay, cy, b_between_a_and_c))
```

output:

```
1 is between 0 and 4: True
4 is between 1 and 3: False
3 is between 4 and 2: False
```